# Understanding higher dimensional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm having trouble understanding higher dimensional derivatives.

Suppose $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.  We say $f$ is *differentiable* at $x = c$ if $\lim \limits_{x \to c} \dfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$ exists.  If the limit exists, we define $f'(c)$ as the value limit.  Since this limit is a number, we can equivalently define the derivative of $f(x)$ at $c$ as the number $q$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} \dfrac{f(x) - f(c) - q(x - c)}{x - c} = 0$.  If such a $q$ exists, we define $f'(c)$ to be this $q$.  We can think of $q$ as a "linear transformation" from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.  **Why is it useful to think of $q$ in this way?  What's the point of thinking about it as a linear transformation?**  I think it probably has something to do with the fact that $f(c) + q(x - c)$ is the tangent *line*.

Now, we can define the derivative of $g: \Bbb R^{n} \to \Bbb R^{m}$ in the same way, that is, if there is some linear transformation $T_{g}$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} \dfrac{||g(x) - g(c) - T_{g}(x - c) ||}{||x - c||} = 0$, then we say $T_{g}$ is the derivative of $g$.  **Again, what's the point of saying this is a linear transformation?** I already know it has to be an $m \times n$ matrix based on the context, but I don't see why we care that it is a linear transformation.  Does it have something to do with the tangent plane?

Comment: Every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a tangent plane attached to it.  The derivative $T_g$ is a map between the tangent plane at the point $c$ and the tangent plane at the point $g(c)$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 You lost me

Comment: It is used to make linear approximations of the function. You can use quadratic, cubic, &c., approximations, but it's not as easy to compute with.

Comment: @Bernard Still too brief for me.  Do you mind adding a detailed explanation as an answer?

Comment: MathInsight.org has a series of pages on understanding just this topic.  [First](http://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_introduction), [second](http://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_definition), [third](http://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_subtleties), [fourth](http://mathinsight.org/linear_approximation_multivariable), and [fifth](http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix).

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks, I've seen those pages before asking this question.  I guess I will just keep rereading them until it sticks.  While the answers given here are helpful, they weren't really angled the way I was hoping.

Comment: I think that the right area of study for getting the fundamentals of differentiability is differential geometry. I myself can't say too much because I'm barely at the beginning. All I can say is that the type of understanding you ask for is in sight, somewhere down the road.

Comment: @GPerez Well, I'm in differential topology now, and we pretty much started talking about smooth maps on the first day.  We didn't really dive into the definition (why would we? this is something I should already understand before this class).  So I've been having trouble understanding smooth maps between Euclidean spaces, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we start out with $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then $f'(c)$ is an approximation of how $f$ changes in a small interval around $x=c$.  For example, let $f(x)=x^3$, and $c=2$.  Then $f'(2)=12$.  Notice that $f(2.01)=8.120601$.  Then the change from $f(2)$ to $f(2.01)$ is $0.120601$.  This is approximately $12(.01)$.

For higher dimensions, the derivative needs to be a transformation between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.  For example, take $f(x,y)=(x+y,y^2)$.  Then the derivative is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2y
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
At $(x,y)=(2,1)$ this is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Moving on, $f(2,1)=(3,1)$ and $f(2.01,1.01)=(3.02,1.0201)$.  The change between the function values is $(0.02,0.0201)$.  Notice that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.01 \\ 0.01
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.02 \\ 0.02
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Again, very close.  So, the derivative is the linear transformation that most closely fits the function.  Since linear transformations are much easier to study than functions in general, we may learn a lot about the function from its derivatives.

Comment: But why are you multiplying $12$ with $.01$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\begin{pmatrix} 0.01 \\ 0.01 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I think it's because with $f'(c)$ we are pretending that our new "origin" is the point $c$.  So to determine how $f$ changes, i.e., the new value of $f$ if we veer away from $c$, we just need to multiply $f'(c)$ by the difference between $c$ and our new point $c + h$, i.e., by the amount we move away from $c$.  Multiplying $f'(c)$ by the amount we move away from $c$ should approximate the value of $f$ at $c + h$.  Is that right?

Comment: So basically, I think you meant to say that $f'(c)(x - c)$ is an approximation of $f$ near $c$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @user46944 Yes.  It the best linear approximation of $f$ near $c$.

Comment: This is so very nice +1. Especially the example in two dimension with the linear operator shown in a matrix form makes the thing a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for the compliment.

Comment: So the idea is that the derivative as a linear transformation is telling us that, if we move $h$ distance from $c$, the derivative acts on this $h$ and outputs how much we *expect* the function to have changed.  In the one dimensional case, if $f'(c)h > 0$, then we expect the function at $c + h$ to be $f'(c)h$ *higher* than the function at $c$.  Does this $h$ also model how we expect the function to change as we move to the left?  For example, does $f'(c)h$ give me information about $f$ at $c - h$?

Comment: Can anyone verify if this is what the answerer meant?

Comment: @user46944 Yes.  It is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the derivative is that it provides `linear approximations` of a function. Using the language of `asymptotic analysis`, we can say that, if $f$ has  a derivative at $a$, then:
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+o(x-a)$$
where $o(x-a)$ — the ‘error term’ when replacing $f(x)$ with $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ — is such that:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{o(x-a)}{x-a}=0,$$
which means, roughly, that  the error term is negligible w.r.t. $\lvert x-a\rvert$.

Similarly, the second derivatice adds some information on this error term:
$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(a)\frac{x^2}{2}+o((x-α)^2).$$
This is a quadratic approximation, known as *Taylor's formula at order* $2 $.

There are similar formulae for functions of several variables, and the derivative of the one-variable case has to be replaced with the differential, which is a `linear form` on $\mathbf R^n$, with coefficients equal to the *partial*  derivatives of $f$. The second derivative becomes a `quadratic form` on  $\mathbf R^n$, defined by the matrix of second order partial derivatives.